# Writing database connection details in my index - security risks?

Tags: php, sql

My website was hacked and my host tells me that somebody is sending massive amounts of spam through my website.
Recently I made these modifications:
1) I deleted the include database_connection file and put its contents in my main page in the header like this:

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","mydb","pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

2) I included a search form like this:

```
<form name="search_form" id="search_form" method="POST" action="">
<span>Search:</span> <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search the data" />
</form>
$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Name) table ";
    if (isset($_POST['search'])){

    $search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
    $sql .="WHERE Name LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";
}
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Can these two modifications let the hackers in?
If yes, is it possible that they infected other files, or I can delete these files and be fine?
Thanks!

Edit: My host provider had to suspend my account several times because "huge amount of data" was sent through my site. I have to find the cause of this..

Comment: What do you mean by 'hacked'? What has happened? Did you find any files modified? Did you find any files on your host that are not yours?

Comment: I did not find any new files. My hosts tells me that somebody is sending "huge amount of data" through my site and they suspended it several times. They pointed out to my wordpress theme as the cause of this. It is a wordpress theme made by me and the only changes that I did in the last two months were these. I was thinking maybe because I put my database and password in the index.php and someone can see them...

Comment: in common, only mysql_real_escape_string related to security (and you sould migrate from mysql extension to mysqli or mysqlnd).

Comment: About wordpress theme: and you didn't make this theme from scratch, I suppose? If answer is "yes", maybe initial theme has security issues.
If "no" - maybe you used unsecure constructions.
Even wordpress core may be outdated

Comment: I did made the theme from scratch. Wordpress has been updated recently. So, I understand that this is not the cause of the problem and I should look somewhere else..

Comment: Perhaps this is injected code... Open each of your PHP files and see if there are any unusual pieces of code. For example, you may find base64 encoded text (somewhat garbled text) with an eval statement. This is often found at the beginning of a php file. Check if this exists. If it does, your server has been hacked. This again is nothing to do with your DB or connection code. Rather a result of bad habbits, phishing, etc.

Comment: I found a lot of base64, like: $value = base64_decode($this->_currentTagContents); but it should be in an eval statement to be malicious right? Thanks again!

Comment: Also check your site network usage through firebug or similar tools. You can see which other domains are being called. Try several pages. If all seems fine, check if your php have been modified in some way.